# Colocar mensaje de "No existen registros" en sentencia preparada usando filtro de búsqueda

Tags: php, mysqli

Elabore un filtro de búsqueda usando sentencias preparadas (este comprueba que campos están vacíos o no en el formulario de búsqueda y agrega la variable que representa dicho campo como un `AND` para la consulta `SQL` , de manera que va construyendo la query: `"SELECT * FROM sanciones WHERE DATO AND DATO1 AND DATO2"`).

***Quisiera que muestre un mensaje cuando no existan resultados, pero no se donde colocar la condicional para evaluar dicha cantidad de resultados encontrados.***

Intente lo siguiente:

**1)** `"SELECT * , COUNT(*) FROM sanciones"`, el problema casi igual que la solución **Nro 4**, solo muestra un registro, así hallan cientos que cumplan las condiciones de búsqueda, ya que esa sentencia no es correcta en SQL.

**2)** La 2da solución implica construir la SQL asi: `"SELECT dato1,dato2,dato3,daton, count(*) FROM sanciones GROUP by DATO1"` realice la moifaciion y quedo algo así:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)
, id_sancion
, unidad
, cedula_sancionado
, cedula_sancionador
, cedula_superior
, articulo_falta 
, aparte_falta  
, documento_seleccion 
, fecha_inicio  
, fecha_termino 
, dias_sancion  
, aclaratoria_sancion 
, estado_sancion_id 
, fecha_proceso 
, medida_id 
, articulo_circunstancias 
, agravante_seleccion 
, atenuante_seleccion 
, total_demerito  
, estado_lugar_id FROM sanciones";
```

*El mismo error de la solución **Nro1** muestra solo 1 resultado asi hallan cientos.*

*Si agrego `GROUP BY dato` me da error la funcuon `call_user_func_array()` pues ella espera un array y sino me equivoco esto se convierte en un solo valor*

**3)** Si comparo la variable `$resultados`: dara error puesto ella es un **Objeto Mysqli**

**4)** Si comparo `$datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc();` que fue lo mas funcional que conseguí, me dirá que si hay datos, pero una vez lo compare se ejecutara la función y me "gastara" por así decirlo, un registro.

Trate colocando este codigo

```
$datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc();
if ($datos < 0) {
    echo '<br /> NO HAY RESULTADOS';
}
while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc()){}
```

Pero recordemos que una vez llame a $datos se ejecuta el programa y ya se "gasta" por así decirlo un registro, por lo que luego mostraria un resultado menos.

Es decir, si agrego eso, **funciona** pero siempre muestra un registro menos del resultado esperado.

Si la consulta daba:

```
OMD: 2

OMD: 3

OMD: 5
```

Que cumplen las coniciones de busqueda.

El `While` solo mostrara `OMD:3` y `OMD:5`

Este es el código:

```
<?php  
//Variables//
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$unidad = $_POST["unidad"];
$cedula1 = $_POST["cedula1"];
$cedula2 = $_POST["cedula2"];
$fechaini = $_POST["fecha_inicio"];
$fechater = $_POST["fecha_termino"];
$tipomedida = $_POST["medida"];
$estadosancion = $_POST["estado"];

//Constantes//
$query = "SELECT * FROM sanciones";
$identificador = "";
$valor = "";
$condiciones = array();
$identificadores = array();
$valores = array();

//Condiciones
  if ($numero != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "id_sancion=?";
  $identificadores[] = "i";
  $valores[] = "$numero";
  }

if ($unidad != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "unidad=?";
  $identificadores[] = "s";
  $valores[] = "$unidad";
  }

if ($cedula1 != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "cedula_sancionado=?";
  $identificadores[] = "i";
  $valores[] = "$cedula1";
  }

if ($cedula2 != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "cedula_sancionador=?";
  $identificadores[] = "i";
  $valores[] = "$cedula2";
  }

if ($fechaini != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "fecha_inicio=?";
  $identificadores[] = "s";
  $valores[] = "$fechaini";
  }

if ($fechater != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "fecha_termino=?";
  $identificadores[] = "s";
  $valores[] = "$fechater";
  }

if ($tipomedida != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "medida_id=?";
  $identificadores[] = "i";
  $valores[] = "$tipomedida";
  }

if ($estadosancion != "")
  {
  $condiciones[] = "estado_sancion_id=?";
  $identificadores[] = "i";
  $valores[] = "$estadosancion";
  }

$query_final = $query;

if (count($condiciones) > 0)
  {
  $query_final.= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $condiciones);
  }

$identificadores_final = $identificador;

if (count($identificadores) > 0)
  {
  $identificadores_final.= implode("", $identificadores);
  }

$valores_final = $valor;

if (count($valores) > 0)
  {
  $valores_final.= implode(',', $valores);
  }

//Referencia para meter los ARRAYS en el bind_param
$n = count($valores);

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
  {
  $valores_ref[$i] = & $valores[$i];
  }

//Ejecutando la sentencia finial
$stmtx = $conexion->prepare($query_final);
call_user_func_array(array($stmtx,"bind_param") , array_merge(array($identificadores_final) , $valores));
$stmtx->execute();
$resultados = $stmtx->get_result();

while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc())
{
}
?>
```

> Quisiera contar la cantidad de registros que saldran y luego si da 0 mostrar un mensaje

Comment: Mas claro no puede estar, al preguntar. por eso no entiendo el voto para ser cerrada?, incluso en el titulo agregue especificamente que proceso estaba usando, como se indica en la guia para "como preguntar?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `$resultados` es un objecto del tipo [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) y posee una propiedad llamada [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) la cual:

> Retorna el número de filas del resultado.

Es decir que si `$resultados->num_rows`, es igual a `cero` (`0`), entonces deberías imprimir *"No existen registros"*

### Solución:

```
// ... código anterior ....
$stmtx->execute();

$resultados = $stmtx->get_result();
if ($resultados->num_rows === 0) {
  // Imprimir "No existen registros"
} else {
  while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Imprimir resultados
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, antes habia tratado num_rows pero no recuerdo donde la puse, y daba error por eso lo borre, creo que no lo puse en $resultados.

Gracias :)